# Custom Lightweight JavaScript Libraries: EnderJS and MicroJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ender

I'm working on a custom lightweight JavaScript library that will need to run stably across the major browsers as well as across numerous independent sites without compromising or being compromised by existing libraries or namespaces. Perhaps most importantly, the library will need to be lightweight (~15k max).

**UPDATE** To clarify the need for such a small library: This is a third-party service that sites would pull into their page. We need to keep everything as light-weight, speedy, and self-contained as possible since we have no control over the existent libraries, speed, or page load. 15k is the target number just for the library that is accessed by the dynamic content of the service.

At this point my idea is to start with the most condensed jQuery-like base I can find, and then extend with custom modules.

**Desired features:**

- Handle cross-browser inconsistencies like a champ (IE 6+, Chrome, FF 2+, Safari 3+).
- Event handling (queuing/binding/broadcasting)
- Efficient selector engine
- Chaining
- DOM manipulation w/ basic animations
- Readily build-able and version-able from modules

I've come across [EnderJS](http://ender.jit.su/) and [MicroJS](http://microjs.com/) but I can't seem to find a lot of discussion on either. I'm more familiar and interested in Ender at this point since it seems to address all of the above features almost out of the box with ["The Jeesh"](http://ender.jit.su/#jeesh) weighing in at 7.5k. Tacking on a couple additional packages only pushes it to 10k in my case which would be perfect since I should only need a few k to flesh out any custom modules. It also would allow me to write and version distinct modules that can be incorporated and compressed into the main library at build-time, as well as define a unique namespace to hold it all together and hopefully protect it. Another compelling piece to the Ender library is its use of [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) which I would love to play around with more anyway. Having said all of that, however, I am still wide open to other ideas.

**So my question is:**

Does anyone have any experience with either [EnderJS](http://ender.jit.su/) or [MicroJS](http://microjs.com/), or have another solution/approach to what I'm trying to accomplish? I realize this is not the place for ["chatty, open-ended questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), and that's not my intent here. I'm just looking for suggestions on the best way to approach building a light-weight custom library without reinventing the wheel and to instead plug into the most up to date micro-libraries available.

Comment: Why do you need it to be ~15k max? What's the design constraint there?

Comment: This is a third party service that sites would pull into their page. We need to keep everything light-weight, speedy, and as self-contained as possible since we have no control over the existant libraries, speed, or page load. 15k is the target number for the library to set the base for other code and content to invoke.

Comment: Thanks for the question T.J. I updated my post to hopefully be more clear on the constraint.

Comment: @johnmdonahue: Then I'd use demand-loaded jQuery using one of the CDNs (Google's or Microsoft's; I think Google's is used more but you'd want to test). Your code can detect whether jQuery is already loaded and use it if so (~0k), and if not add a `script` element dynamically that pulls it from the CDN. If the user has visited any other site using jQuery from that CDN, then the script may well come from cache (~0k). If not, granted, then you have the ~31k rather than ~15k hit, but again, quite frequently you won't have any hit, or just the hit of a "not modified" response from the CDN.

Comment: @johnmdonahue: *(Continuing)* You'd want to issue a `noConflict` call if you did load it, in case the site uses `$` for something other than jQuery. That's readily done by watching for the `load` event on the `script` element (you have to use `readystatechange` on IE and watch for either `loaded` or `complete` status) and then doing it when that comes through.

Comment: @Crowder Sounds like an answer, should post it (that's what I would have done)

Comment: @mazzzzz: I was thinking it didn't really answer the question *asked*, but maybe...

Comment: @Crowder That's a good idea but unfortunately not really an option for us. I agree jQuery from Google's CDN would most likely be cached - saving load - and that we could check and extend as needed, but it doesn't seem as scalable or stable as serving it ourselves. The site could decide to overwrite some jQuery module to suit their needs or worse. What we need is a light-weight self-contained library that we have complete control over and can extend and branch as needed. The goal is that this library will be cached and versioned from our CDN.

Comment: @Crowder, It does, he asks for a way to do it, and there aren't any (well supported) libraries that have that size.  This will give you the best of both words, with use of cache, and pre-initalized libraries, you'll cut it down to the smallest possible size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've used Ender recently, and I've had no issues with it really. There are a couple of jQuery functions that aren't available from the off, but anyone who is fairly adept at JavaScript can circumvent this. Especially given the fact that Ender has a near identical structure and way of extending as jQuery.

I've used Ender on a live site recently and funnily enough I have used a couple of scripts from microjs.com alongside my own functions file, and all the JavaScript weighed in at around 15k. It's not hard to make your entire site code weigh around that or less.

As well as building a lightweight version of Ender, for example starting with the Jeesh, you might also want to consider async loading, an example is provided by [Dustin Diaz](https://gist.github.com/1053078):

```
<script src="ender.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.require('/js/core.min.js', 'core')

$.ready('core', function () {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('<p>hello world</p>').appendTo('body')
      .bind('click', function (e) {
        $.require('/js/ajax.min.js', function () {
          $(e.target).css('position', 'relative')
            .animate({
              left: 500
            })
        })
      })
  })
})
</script>
```

By doing this you could essentially make the original ender build even lighter, and defer some of the loading, but generally speaking, if it's light in the first place you should be ok.

You might also want to take advantage of the Google closure compiler that Ender gives you access to in order to compile your site code alongside ender.

Finally, as you're probably well aware, you can do noConflict in Ender as well, just in case they already have another library present.

As you build and configure Ender you will probably want to take advantage of [ender-wallet](https://github.com/stenson/wallet) which will give you a sort of API view, allowing you to remove libraries you might not need at all.

hotlinked screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is ender that much smaller than jQuery? What's the overall benefit?

Comment: In terms of physical filesize, Ender is way smaller. With a pretty full featureset, Ender weighs around 15k minified, whereas jQuery is around 90k. Gzipped, they both become a lot smaller. The main argument is that jQuery is pretty much everywhere and there is a likelihood that your user has a cached version already, and gzipped, served from a CDN, the footprint is no more then you would expect for an image in your page. I prefer the concept behind Ender, it's very flexible and has a bright future.

Comment: @Kirk The interesting thing for me about ender is in the build process. I like the idea of maintaining submodules that extend a core, custom selected library. A group of small, independent, commented and versioned modules that I can package together at build time into a compressed custom library. I could do this by forking jQuery, stripping out what I don't need and setting up some kind of ant build process, but it's already provided in Ender + Node. It's not as much about size (although that is important), as it is about customization and extending a basic core library exactly for my purpose.

Comment: @Fazal Thanks for your input! And ender-wallet looks cool. I'll definitely look into that. It would be awesome if that could tie into self-documentation, using something like JSDoc Toolkit or YUIDoc.

Answer (score 16):

I'm one of the co-creators of Ender and I'll +1 Fazal's words.

A note on the Jeesh, albeit a nice starter-pack to Ender, the true power lies in the ability to extend Ender with its growing set of modules. You can check them out here: https://github.com/ender-js/Ender/wiki/Ender-package-list

Somehow, one way or another Ender became the forefront of "micro library" development, but really what we're after is putting a cohesive interface onto loosely coupled modules (however large or small they are). jQuery took a great first step in abstracting its selector engine (Sizzle), but unfortunately the rest of it is interdependent (dom, events, animation, ajax, utils, promises), thus making it impossible to pick and pull what you want.

On another aside, one of the neat things about Ender is the ability to publish modules to NPM and being able to port them into your project `by name` allowing you to `build only what you need, when you need it`

It's worth checking out the learn videos at http://enderjs.com/learn which will give you a better idea of how packages are authored, built, and consumed. You'll find that setting up Ender into your environment is extremely simple and actually quite fun to work with.

Let us (@ded or @fat) know if you have any questions and we'll be more than willing to help sort things out

Comment: Thanks! I've started playing around some and it seems like a perfect fit for my current project.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that ender -b jeesh is telling me the library size is 8.1k but when I inspect the ender.min.js file, it shows 22k. Where is the 7.5k (8.1k) number coming from? gzipped?

Comment: the 8k comes from the gzip size. I'm currently looking to see how I can get S3/cloudfront to allow gzipping, but in the meantime it's really easy to get it working on your own web servers running on Apache or even in your Node apps with the gzip module

Answer (score 4):

Given this:

> To clarify the need for such a small library: This is a third-party service that sites would pull into their page. We need to keep everything as light-weight, speedy, and self-contained as possible since we have no control over the existant libraries, speed, or page load. 15k is the target number just for the library that is accessed by the dynamic content of the service.

I'd recommend using demand-loaded jQuery via one of the CDNs (Google's or Microsoft's; I think Google's is used more but you'd want to test). Your code can detect whether jQuery is already loaded and use it if so (~0k), and if not add a `script` element dynamically that pulls it from the CDN. If the user has visited any other site using jQuery from that CDN, then the script may well come from cache (~0k). If not, granted, then you have the ~31k rather than ~15k hit, but again, quite frequently you won't have any hit, or just the hit of a "not modified" response from the CDN.

You'd want to issue a `noConflict` call if you did load it, in case the site uses `$` for something other than jQuery. That's readily done by watching for the `load` event on the `script` element (you have to use `readystatechange` on IE and watch for either `loaded` or `complete` status) and then doing it when that comes through.

In today's telecomms world, the difference between a 15k download and a 31k download is *trivial* compared with the cost of setting up the HTTP connection in the first place.

That demand-load really is a tiny bit of code, along these lines:

```
function loadJQuery(cb) {
    var d, s, t;

    if (typeof jQuery === "function"
        && parseFloat(jQuery.fn.jquery) >= 1.5) { /* Or whatever */
        window.ourjQuery = jQuery;
        if (cb) {
            cb();
        }
        return;
    }

    d = document;
    s = d.createElement('script');
    t = d.body || d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || d.documentElement;

    s.onload = loaded;
    s.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;
    s.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
    t.appendChild(s);

    function loaded() {
        if (s) {
            s = undefined;
            window.ourjQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            if (cb) {
                cb();
            }
        }
    }

    function handleReadyStateChange() {
        if (s && (s.readyState === "loaded" || s.readyState === "complete")) {
            loaded();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the URL on the `script` element. That's so it's friendly to both `http` and `https` pages ([details](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html)). Note also that I'm checking for a minimum jQuery version and using the more rigorous form of `noConflict` if we load it. Either way, by the time the callback is called, the `ourjQuery` symbol refers to the loaded copy with the minimum version.

---

**Update**: Addressing your comment above:

> That's a good idea but unfortunately not really an option for us. I agree jQuery from Google's CDN would most likely be cached - saving load - and that we could check and extend as needed, but it doesn't seem as scalable or stable as serving it ourselves. The site could decide to overwrite some jQuery module to suit their needs or worse. What we need is a light-weight self-contained library that we have complete control over and can extend and branch as needed. The goal is that this library will be cached and versioned from our CDN.

Yes, there's a small risk of a site having modified basic jQuery functionality. A ***very*** small risk. If you're restricting yourself to the core API (not plugins and such) I frankly don't think it's worth worrying about.

But if you're worried about that, then frankly I'd just use a slightly-modified jQuery hosted on your own CDN using a different symbol than `jQuery` (and not using `$` at all). 31k vs. 15k in today's telecomms world is a non-issue; the primary cost will be in establishing the connection in the first place. If you wanted, you could probably pare that down a bit by removing parts you don't need, although sadly the jQuery internals are a bit of a morass and selectively removing functionality may not be trivial (depending on what functionality it is).

Comment: I can see where this makes perfect sense in some cases, but my concern is over control. Which version of jQuery is on the page? What muddling did the site happen to do with it before injecting my script? Etc. I would need another "library", albeit small, to handle checking, loading, and extending jQuery, which I would not want to do directly to the site's instance, so I would need to make a copy of a possibly tampered object. It could also require waiting for page load, which I do not have the luxury of doing either. I need to be able to execute the specific code I need exactly when I need it.

Comment: This is exactly where I am: "But if you're worried about that, then frankly I'd just use a slightly-modified jQuery"... That's why Ender appeals to me so much. ;)

Comment: @johnmdonahue: The code to load jQuery and check the version is trivial (above). If you stick to the basic functionality, my assertion is you can disregard the idea of anyone having tampered with that. There's certainly no reason to *copy* the lib if it's there. No need to wait for page load, just tell the sites that would utilize your service that if they load scripts, they should load yours last. But you know the overall project and design constraints dramatically better than I do, if the above won't work, it won't work. I'd at least discuss it with your team, though. Good luck with it,

Comment: @Crowder I'm sorry I can't be any more specific here, but I can say with confidence that in my situation this solution will not work and that control and file size (although seemingly trivial) are very important. I like the solution, but the intent of my question was to get suggestions on building and extending custom modular libraries and learn about people's experiences with the tools mentioned (MicroJS / Ender) or otherwise. I absolutely did leave it open to alternative approaches and I agree, this is a very good one, but unfortunately it won't work in this situation. Thank you though!

Comment: @johnmdonahue: No worries, as I say, *you're* the one who knows the project! Good luck with it,

Comment: @Crowder I meant to note as well, that this script should do the majority of its work before page load. Thanks again!

Comment: @johnmdonahue: The above will work before pageload (should work regardless of when you include it; you might have to adjust the `t = ...` line). It does ideally want to be after the script tag loading jQuery, if the page already has one, but that's just to avoid redundant loads.

Comment: "31k vs. 15k in today's telecomms world is a non-issue" this is first-world thinking, we're in the UK and build for all over the world and first thing we do is check available bandwidth / networks. Most 3rd world countries are using 2g or 3g mobile networks that are oversubscribed and slow. Trust me, 15k makes a lot of difference when you have a JS app stack on top of that!

Comment: @RobEvans: Remember that those 2G/3G users may be saving 15k because of having the relevant jQuery already cached! (Probably not on a mobile device, but if that's their desktop connection...) But yeah, you always have to consider your target users. If most of mine were on 2G/3G connections, I'd probably either consider not using jQuery, or investing in making jQuery (or a subset thereof) compatible with the Closure Compiler in advanced mode (non-trivial), and using CC to compile all of my stuff together for maximum compression. Of course,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So true. CC advanced is really great. jQuery or other browser normalisation library is kinda required as the target audience can still be using (ergh) IE 6, 7 and 8 as well as older mobile browsers. It's a total minefield. Still... remember what it was like 5 years ago? I complain but actually we're so much better off than we used to be doing web dev! :)

Comment: @RobEvans: Big time. :-)